# Makefile support for Tiny C Compiler

Tags: compile, c, makefile

I just found the brilliant [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/) while searching for a small portable C compiler for Windows (I cannot install anything on this system or copy files to it and so need to compile directly on it). According to the introduction "TCC compiles so *fast* that even for big projects Makefiles may not be necessary." But I have source code for a command line program that has many different makefiles for Borland C, Visual C++... How do I use the makefiles with this compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Compiler being fast does not mean that Makefile makes no sense. Makefiles also helps you organize file dependency and less command you have to write every time you want to compile. If you have many makefiles you can still use them. In making things easier write

Answer (score 0):

You can now use busybox with Tiny C which includes a shell and make program.

There is also a pre-configured busybox for Win32 available for download:

http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/tcc-busybox-for-win32.zip

on the About.txt

> ### BUSYBOX FOR TCC
>
> This are pre-configured busybox-w32 (https://frippery.org/busybox/)
> and gnu-make sources for usage with tcc on win32.
>
> To get started:
>
> - Extract this package.
> - Fill the empty tcc subdirectory with a binary tcc such as from
>   tcc-0.9.27-win32|64-bin.zip.
> - Run makebox.bat. This creates **sh.exe** (busybox) and **make.exe** and
>   then enters a little demo menu to show what you can do with it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWQS9.jpg)